# Validate amount of digits in number with an attribute

Tags: c#, .net, validation, attributes, range

I'm currently working on a .net5.0 application.

In my view model class I need to validate a numeric input for it's length.

The property to validate is called "PostalCode" and has the equivalent in the DB: NUMBER(4,0)

The PostalCode can be numeric, without decimal values and within a range from 0000 to 9999.
**Important is, the value must be 4 digits long.**

So far I tried this code:

```
[Range(0, 9999, ErrorMessageResourceType = "The PostalCode must be 4 digits long.")]
public int PostalCode { get; set; }
```

Do you know how to validate the PostalCode with a minimum length of 4 digits correctly?

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The mechanism you are looking for is "Regular Expression" and there is the "RegexAttribute" for that one :-)

Comment: Thanks, good point Codexer - best regards from Europe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{4})$", ErrorMessage = "The PostalCode must be 4 digits long.")]
public int PostalCode { get; set; }
```